# Same but Different! Renaming Multiple Files using R

Tags: r

I am new to R coding and I am in the process of trying to write code in order to rename a series of pdf files in the same folder:

```
Letter131.pdf
Letter132.pdf
Letter133.pdf
```

There are likely to be ~1000 files that I will eventually need to rename.

I would like to rename these files so that they have an "_" between the 2nd and 3rd digits:

```
Letter13_1.pdf
Letter13_2.pdf
Letter13_3.pdf
```

I have found various answers on renaming multiple files and unfortunately I am unable to re-jig them to work.

One example I have come up with is this:

```
file_names <- list.files(pattern="*.pdf")
sapply(file_names, FUN = function(eachPath){
  file.rename(from = eachPath, to = sub(pattern = "Letter13$.pdf", paste0("Letter13_$"), 1:3, eachPath))
})
```

Is anyone able to help me out on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file.rename` is vectorized , no need to use a loop here:

```
## insert _ using grouping pattern
TO <- sub('(.*)([0-9][.]pdf)','\\1_\\2',file_names)
## rename a vector 
file.rename(file_names , TO)
```

Example of pattern use :

```
file_names <- c("Letter131.pdf","Letter132.pdf","Letter133.pdf")
sub('(.*)([0-9][.]pdf)','\\1_\\2',file_names)  
## [1] "Letter13_1.pdf" "Letter13_2.pdf" "Letter13_3.pdf"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Worked a treat. Just one question: if I want to use the code for up to 1000 different pdf files, do I change the value [0-9] to [0-1000]?

Comment: Not clear.  this code will insert "_" before the last digit (even for for 1000 files).

Comment: Sorry my misunderstanding. Thank you for your help - that's awesome.